# Trouble with UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I'm having problems trying to use the UPDATE query in SQL server.
this is my query:

```
UPDATE THEATER 
SET SeatsAvailable = SeatsAvailable - 1 
FROM THEATER 
INNER JOIN CINEMA_SESSION ON CINEMA_SESSION.tid = THEATER.tid 
WHERE THEATER.tid = 2 AND CINEMA_SESSION.sid = 2
```

-tid is the pk for THEATER
-sid is the pk for CINEMA_SESSION

When I use a SELECT statement to search for the SeatsAvailable in CINEMA_SESSION.sid = 3, which also has .tid=2, it also comes with the updated value for the CINEMA_SESSION.sid = 2.
The statement that I'm using is this simple Select statement:

```
SELECT THEATER.SeatsAvailable as SeatsAvailable FROM THEATER 
INNER JOIN CINEMA_SESSION ON CINEMA_SESSION.tid = THEATER.tid 
WHERE CINEMA_SESSION.sid = 3 AND THEATER.tid = 2
```

Here I want to specify the THEATER.tid which is the same in the UPDATE query but in a different CINEMA_SESSION.sid in which the SeatsAvailable should have remained the same.

Comment: I was going to offer an answer, as I think I can guess the problem, but I'm having to make too many assumptions. Can you [edit] your question to confirm that `tid` is the primary key for `Theater`, and `sid` is the primary key for `Cinema_Session`, and show the `select` referred to in your final paragraph,  which I suspect will join on `tid`.

Comment: Your assumption was correct, I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update statement is decrementing the value of SeatsAvailable on the Theatre table for `tid`=2 (the `AND CINEMA_SESSION.sid = 2` is immaterial - you are updating the row on the `THEATER` table). Since `tid` is the primary key for theatre, there is only one record with that value, and that record is updated.

Your `select` for session `sid=3` joins to `theatre` by the `tid` column, and it's matching the row where tid=2, which is why you're seeing the new value - it is matching the record that you just updated.

This may make more sense if you just look at the contents of the THEATER table (without any joins).

If you are trying to indicate that a seat has been booked for a particular session, then I would suggest you need to be updating a field on a different table. I'll leave that to you to work out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I understood why it did not work and changed my approach. Created a new table to store the updated seats that also has as primary key tid from theaters and sid from cinema_session. Might be better ways of doing it but it's improvement